# Blazor browser-side opens print menu

Tags: printing, blazor

I am sending data from a `.NET Core app` to a Blazor client via a websocket , after which  via the interop , the data gets in my component.
I do not understand why when i am trying `Server-Side` it works ok ,the app has the desired behaviour , while when changing the project to `Browser` i get a `Print Menu` pop-up like the one below. (I have some `#define` where i can choose at ease between `Server-Hosted` or `Browser`)
How can Blazor do this pop-up ?

[image]

When i press cancel on the print menu i get the following error in the browser:

> blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM: * Assertion at
>   /mnt/jenkins/workspace/test-mono-mainline-wasm/label/ubuntu-1804-amd64/mono/mini/wasm_m2n_invoke.g.h:547,
>   condition `0' not met
>   blazor.webassembly.js:1 Uncaught
>   (in promise) abort(). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.

How can blazor open a print menu ?

Comment: Are you using `Math.Round`? [Math.Round opens the browser print dialog #290](https://github.com/dotnet/try/issues/290)  

Comment: No i am not , however i am setting the size of a 2D array.And it seems at that point the print pop-up opens.

Comment: I guess you should to isolate problem and open an issue on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not understand why when i am trying Server-Side it works ok ,the
>   app has the desired behaviour , while when changing the project to
>   Browser i get a Print Menu pop-up like the one below.

Websockets are not supported on client-side Blazor. They are supported only on the server... Perhaps this is why your client-side Blazor misbehaves.

Comment: Well i manage to pass the data from the socket in `js` to the `[JSInvokeable]` static method and from there i fire an event (with the data) to which my component subscribes.In the event handler of my component it misbehaves , not in js , not in the static `jsinvokeable` method.

Comment: Sorry, can't say what ails your code without seeing it. Did you try to verify whether it is related to what @dani herrera referred to in his comment ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with WebSockets from WebAssembly. See https://github.com/Lupusa87/BlazorWebSocketHelper (a little out of date, but still)